# How to get xinput device ID of touchscreen without using manufacturer string?

Tags: x11, udev, chrome, yocto, touch-screen

Chromium only shows proper touchscreen behavior when the supplied ID argument is 7 in the case of the below devices.
Note that the xinput IDs are subject to change during a reboot, so I can't just use 7 all the time.

I understand I can whitelist manufacturer strings but I would like something reliable that always works and doesn't depend on manufacturer strings staying the same.

**DEVICE 1:**

```
Touchscreen Hardware on device 1 (reported by xinput):
? Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
? ? Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
? ? ADS7846 Touchscreen id=9 [slave pointer (2)]
? ? NHD Newhaven Display id=7 [slave pointer (2)]
? Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
? Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
? 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
? Dell Dell USB Entry Keyboard id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

```
/dev/input/touchscreen0 -> /dev/input/event1
```

```
udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/input/event1
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-NHD_Newhaven_Display-event-if00 /dev/input/by-path/platform-ci_hdrc.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event /dev/input/touchscreen0
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event1
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/soc/30800000.aips-bus/30b10000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0461:0022.005C/input/input93/event1
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1
ID_MODEL=Newhaven_Display
ID_MODEL_ENC=Newhavenx20Displayx20
ID_MODEL_ID=0022
ID_PATH=platform-ci_hdrc.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-ci_hdrc_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0100
ID_SERIAL=NHD_Newhaven_Display
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030102:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=NHD
ID_VENDOR_ENC=NHD
ID_VENDOR_ID=0461
LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX=1.066870 -0.005907 -0.026620 0.007245 -1.136364 1.046200
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/461/22:usb-ci_hdrc.0-1
MAJOR=13
MINOR=65
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=514876494495
```

**DEVICE 2:**

```
Touchscreen Hardware on device 2 (reported by xinput):
? Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
? Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
? Silicon Integrated System Co. SiS HID Touch Controller Mouse id=8 [slave pointer (2)]
? Silicon Integrated System Co. SiS HID Touch Controller Touchscreen id=7 [slave pointer (2)]
? ADS7846 Touchscreen id=9 [slave pointer (2)]
? Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
? Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
? 30370000.snvs:snvs-powerkey id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

```
/dev/input/touchscreen0 -> /dev/input/event3 (event1 seems like the correct touchscreen though,
based on the udevadm output)
```

```
udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/input/event1
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/platform-ci_hdrc.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event /dev/input/touchscreen0 /dev/input/by-id/usb-Silicon_Integrated_System_Co._SiS_HID_Touch_Controller-event-if00
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event1
DEVPATH=/devices/soc0/soc/30800000.aips-bus/30b10000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:04E7:1080.0001/input/input1/event1
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_HEIGHT_MM=136
ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=1
ID_INPUT_WIDTH_MM=215
ID_MODEL=SiS_HID_Touch_Controller
ID_MODEL_ENC=SiSx20HIDx20Touchx20Controller
ID_MODEL_ID=1080
ID_PATH=platform-ci_hdrc.0-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=platform-ci_hdrc_0-usb-0_1_1_0
ID_REVISION=0100
ID_SERIAL=Silicon_Integrated_System_Co._SiS_HID_Touch_Controller
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Silicon_Integrated_System_Co.
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Siliconx20Integratedx20Systemx20Co.
ID_VENDOR_ID=04e7
LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX=1.066870 -0.005907 -0.026620 0.007245 -1.136364 1.046200
LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/4e7/1080:usb-ci_hdrc.0-1
MAJOR=13
MINOR=65
SUBSYSTEM=input
USEC_INITIALIZED=8612683
```

Edit:

This is the output of xinput list --long. (I removed the irrelevant devices):

```
⎜   ↳ ADS7846 Touchscreen                       id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
        Reporting 4 classes:
                Class originated from: 7. Type: XIButtonClass
                Buttons supported: 5
                Button labels: "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down"
                Button state:
                Class originated from: 7. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 0:
                  Label: Abs X
                  Range: 0.000000 - 4095.000000
                  Resolution: 0 units/m
                  Mode: absolute
                  Current value: 512.000000
                Class originated from: 7. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 1:
                  Label: Abs Y
                  Range: 0.000000 - 4095.000000
                  Resolution: 0 units/m
                  Mode: absolute
                  Current value: 384.000000
                Class originated from: 7. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 2:
                  Label: Abs Pressure
                  Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
                  Resolution: 0 units/m
                  Mode: absolute
                  Current value: 0.000000
⎜   ↳ NHD Newhaven Display                      id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
        Reporting 3 classes:
                Class originated from: 8. Type: XIButtonClass
                Buttons supported: 5
                Button labels: "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down"
                Button state:
                Class originated from: 8. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 0:
                  Label: Abs X
                  Range: 0.000000 - 10000.000000
                  Resolution: 0 units/m
                  Mode: absolute
                  Current value: 4379.000000
                Class originated from: 8. Type: XIValuatorClass
                Detail for Valuator 1:
                  Label: Abs Y
                  Range: 0.000000 - 10000.000000
                  Resolution: 0 units/m
                  Mode: absolute
                  Current value: 7896.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was performing the following command over all /dev/input/event* nodes:

```
udevadm info --query=property --name=<event-node>
```

Since I was searching for a device that was a touchscreen and that was connected via USB, I searched the output for a case where the output contained:

```
ID_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN = 1
ID_BUS = usb
```

I then had to use the following command over all xinput IDs (You can get the list of IDs with xinput list --id-only):

```
xinput list-props <ID> | grep <touchscreen-input-node>
```

That gave me the ID required to supply the --touch-devices argument for chromium.